# Need generic method to return type T unless T implements interface I, in which case return I

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a generic method which returns a type T. Now I want to modify it so that if T happens to implement interface I, an additional property is set on the object (i.e. from I).

Something like this (but of course this does not work):

```
    public T MyMethod<T>()
    {
        T resultAsT = some function ....

        var resultAsI = (resultAsT as I);

        if (resultAsI != null)
        {
            resultAsI.PropertyOnlyAvailableInI = 99;
            return resultAsI;
        }
        else
            return resultAsT;
    }
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Your method signature demands that you return T, not I.  So this can't work.

Comment: Why not? With some casting trickery and advance knowledge of the types, it should be possible (but not necessarily a good idea)... they just need need to do `return ((T)resultAsI);` to satisfy the method signature, no?

Comment: @KyleBaran: since they know the object is a `T`, they can cast `resultAsI`. But that doesn't solve anything. That's the same as just returning `resultAsT` (i.e. it's the same object reference), and it doesn't change the _method's_ return type to `I` as the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
public T MyMethod<T>()
{
    T resultAsT = some function ....

    var resultAsI = (resultAsT as I);

    if (resultAsI != null)
    {
        resultAsI.PropertyOnlyAvailableInI = 99;
    }
    return resultAsT;
}
```

The method cannot return anything except `T`, so you should always return `resultAsT`.

Comment: @Laurence: and how does this change the return type of the method? The return type remains the same, and in fact this example is exactly like the one in your question, except that it always explicitly returns the object as `T`. And you down-voted us for not being able to somehow psychically figure out that you wanted an answer to a different question than the one you actually asked? Too rich.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to make it work then you can do so:

```
 public object MyMethod()
     {
         object resultAsT = something;

    var resultAsI = (resultAsT as ISomething);

    if (resultAsI != null)
    {
        resultAsI.PropertyOnlyAvailableInI = 99;
        return resultAsI;
    }
    else
        return resultAsT;
}
```

But it seems to me that you want to do factory that implements the strategy pattern.
Where the object is created with the use of strategy pattern is executed to initialize certain properties of the object.